# How can I start the race from a checkpoint with GTA 5 Map Editor?

Tags: maps, modding

When I use the official Map Editor from GTA V then it seems that you are only able to test the Map from the Start Point all the time. This is very annoying when you build a hardcore difficult Map and you don´t want to start all the time again from the Start Point.

Is there a way to start the Race from as example Checkpoint #3 instead of always from the Start Point? I think there must be a way because I can´t imagine that hardcore difficult Map Builders always restart the Map from the Start Point..

Btw I can't ask the question at rockstar forum because you need to be 1 month online with your account before you can ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you only can manually spawn at each checkpoint but only with your default vehicle! This means at transform races it will sadly not help you! Very uncomfortable at all..

In general this checkpoint test system isn´t build good.. However maybe rockstar will add some changes to this..